# Client Loading More times in token end point

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

Token api I am using `http://localhost:8086/oauth/token` with grant type password
Input:

```
username:user
password:password
grant_type:password
```

**First hit After running the application:**
1)Client is loading is 4 times (loadClientByClientId method from ClientDetailsService interface)
2)Authenticating user one time (authenticate method from AuthenticationManager interface)
3)Again Client Authenticating 3 times

From second hit:
Client is loading 4 times
Authenticating user one time

**AuthorizationServerConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    MongoClientDetailsService clientdetailservice;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientdetailservice);

        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

**MongoClientDetailsService:**

```
@Primary
@Service
public class MongoClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "web-client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "web-client-secret";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1 * 6 * 60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6 * 60 * 60;

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
        System.out.println("loadClientByClientId");
        BaseClientDetails clientDetails = new BaseClientDetails();
        clientDetails.setClientId(CLIEN_ID);
        clientDetails.setAuthorizedGrantTypes(Arrays.asList(GRANT_TYPE, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT));
        clientDetails.setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
        clientDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST));
        clientDetails.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
        clientDetails.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
        clientDetails.setAuthorities(getAuthority());
        return clientDetails;

    }

    private List getAuthority() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }

}
```

**MyAuthenticationManager:**

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("authenticate");
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("123", "123", getAuthority());
    }

    private List getAuthority() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }

}
```

**Logs after hitting api:**

```
2020-01-17 00:17:26.204 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2020-01-17 00:17:26.204 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.205 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2020-01-17 00:17:26.205 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.206 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.207 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /logout'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2020-01-17 00:17:26.209 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.210 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'web-client'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.211 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
loadClientByClientId
2020-01-17 00:17:26.214 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8c4296e2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@cce1ec64: Username: web-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
2020-01-17 00:17:26.214 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.214 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2020-01-17 00:17:26.214 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.215 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.216 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8c4296e2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@cce1ec64: Username: web-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.216 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.216 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@248deced
2020-01-17 00:17:26.216 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.216 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.217 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2020-01-17 00:17:26.217 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2020-01-17 00:17:26.218 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8c4296e2: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@cce1ec64: Username: web-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
2020-01-17 00:17:26.222 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@484f35da, returned: 1
2020-01-17 00:17:26.222 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2020-01-17 00:17:26.222 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2020-01-17 00:17:26.222 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-01-17 00:17:26.228 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint#postAccessToken(Principal, Map)
loadClientByClientId
loadClientByClientId
loadClientByClientId
2020-01-17 00:17:26.246 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] .o.p.p.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter : Getting access token for: web-client
authenticate
loadClientByClientId
loadClientByClientId
loadClientByClientId
2020-01-17 00:17:26.299 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@4f98e90
2020-01-17 00:17:26.305 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2020-01-17 00:17:26.305 DEBUG 6432 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup. That's known. Spring Security hits your store a bunch of times during the authentication process.

Comment: Can I know the reason why authenticating more times?